# String date to DayOfWeek

Tags: c#

This code is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
this.dateValue = "8/12/2005";

return DateTime.dateValue.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

I want to use my dateValue in stead of 'NOW'

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, this won't even compile as written.

Comment: I think this made more sense before the edit...

Comment: (The duplicate doesn't have the same format, but you should be able to figure out what to do from it.)

Comment: @Liath you mean the edit where I removed the snippet? Because this isn't web code and it's not JavaScript?

Comment: I want to convert "8/12/2005" To a day of the week –  Awa 10 secs ago    edit

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I think the original was a bit misleading... hence why I originally got my question the wrong way around. You're right - good edit and dup

Answer (score 4):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
this.dateValue = "8/12/2005";
DateTime dt;
// assuming the expected date is the 8th of Dec 2005, otherwise use m/d/yyyy
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(this.dateValue, "d/m/yyyy", CulterInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
{
    return dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
} 
else 
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `DateTime.Now` property returns a DateTime, DayOfWeek is a property of DateTime so you can simply do

```
return DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

To get the text version of the current Day of the Week

If you want to reverse this you can parse a new DateTime from the string.

```
return DateTime.Parse("8/12/2005").DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Watch our for strings which can't be parsed. You may want to look into the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: He's asking how to use his date *instead* of `Now`, not how to use `Now` instead of his date.

Comment: I want to convert "8/12/2005"
To a day of the week

Comment: @Servy, thanks that wasn't my impression from the original question. I've edited to include both.

Comment: It's recommended you use, at the very least, `ParseExact` when trying to parse a date of a particular format. `Parse` assumes the expected format from the current system environment which may not always match up with the input format.